# Flutter excel set column default width

Tags: excel, flutter, dart

Is there a way to set a default column width when I build an excel file with excel package?

I tried with this
`//set columns width to max`
`/*for (int z = 0; z < 7; z++) {`
`sheet.setColWidth(z, 20);`
`}*/`
but it doesn't work (it sets only the last column width)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.